# Which timestamp format is this eg: 20180130T043000Z

Tags: javascript, ruby, timestamp

Could someone tell me which format is this timestamp eg: `20180130T043000Z`

Comment: The date is `YYYYMMDD` followed by a `T` and the time as `HHMMSS` and followed by the timezone.

Comment: @jabaa yes, but whats the name of this format?

Comment: It's [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). According to the Wikipedia link the date and time are in _basic format_. You can see the exact format in the upper right box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) *basic format*.

The date is formatted as `YYYYMMDD`. The time starts with a `T` and is formatted as `hhmmss`. The `Z` is the timezone and stands for UTC.

- `YYYY` year, 4-digits, zero padded
- `MM` month, 2-digits, zero padded
- `DD` day, 2-digits, zero padded
- `T` time prefix
- `hh` hour, 2-digits, zero padded
- `mm` minute, 2-digits, zero padded
- `ss` second, 2-digits, zero padded
- `Z` timezone, UTC

The full format is `YYYYMMDDThhmmssZ`.